# How to regain quorum in Zookeper Cluster when lost majority of servers permanently?

Tags: apache-zookeeper, quorum

Is there any solution to regain quorum in Zookeper Cluster when lost majority (for example 3 out of 5) of servers permanently? Can we reach quorum somehow again? I read about dynamic reconfiguration, but as i understand the quorum is needded to perform reconfiguration [" a quorum of the old configuration is required to be available and connected for ZooKeeper to be able to make progress"](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/r3.6.3/zookeeperReconfig.html). How to deal with such a situation without loosing data?